# Run a bash command with variables as a python subprocess

Tags: python, bash, algolia

I have this shell command:

`$ docker run -it --env-file=.env -e "CONFIG=$(cat /path/to/your/config.json | jq -r tostring)" algolia/docsearch-scraper`

And I want to run it as a python subprocess.
I thought I'll only need an equivalent of the `jq -r tostring`, but if I use the config.json as a normal string the " don't get escaped. I also escaped them by using json.load(config.json).
With the original jq command the " don't get escaped either and it's just returning the json string.

When I use the json returned as a string in python subprocess i get always a FileNotFoundError on the subprocess line.

```
@main.command()
def algolia_scrape():
    with open(f"{WORKING_DIR}/conf_dev.json") as conf:
        CONFIG = json.load(conf)
        subprocess.Popen(f'/usr/local/bin/docker -it --env-file={WORKING_DIR}/algolia.env -e "CONFIG={json.dumps(CONFIG)}" algolia/docsearch-scraper')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You get "file not found" because (without `shell=True`) you are trying to run a command whose name is `/usr/local/bin/docker -it ...` when you want to run `/usr/local/bin/docker` with some arguments. And of course it would be pretty much a nightmare to try to pass the JSON through the shell because you need to escape any shell metacharacters from the string; but just break up the command string into a list of strings, like the shell would.

```py
def algolia_scrape():
    with open(f"{WORKING_DIR}/conf_dev.json") as conf:
        CONFIG = json.load(conf)
    p = subprocess.Popen(['/usr/local/bin/docker', '-it',
        f'--env-file={WORKING_DIR}/algolia.env',
        '-e', f'CONFIG={json.dumps(CONFIG)}',
        'algolia/docsearch-scraper'])
```

You generally want to save the result of `subprocess.Popen()` because you will need to `wait` for the process when it terminates.

Comment: Could arguably avoid the load/dump round-trip by putting the literal text of the config file (with any trailing whitespace stripped) on the command line.

Comment: Thank you. That was it. But now i get "Unknown shorthand flag 'i' in -it". Somebody has a workaround for that as well?

Comment: I guess you meant `docker run -it`?